# OpenRefine speed puzzlement

Tags: openrefine

I am curious about OpenRefine's speed. I have two projects about 5 MB in size about 35,000-40,000 lines in length.

This dataset works normally: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whanley/egypt-data/main/exp-manifests-rough(1).tsv

This dataset works slowly: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whanley/b-g/master/bslc-members/bslc-members-to-1900-tsv.tsv

I notice the slow speed when faceting. For example, faceting the second dataset column "Surname" by count is very slow.

I have tried increasing memory, etc. What confuses me is the difference in speeds between two quite similar projects. Any insight or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: The first dataset doesn't have a column named "Surname." The second dataset has almost 15K distinct surnames among the 40K lines. That number of choices is very slow for most browsers to render, which is why the default limit on the number of choices is much lower.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Re "most browsers," is there a browser that is faster than others? I've lowered the default and seen better performance.

Comment: Sure, there are performance differences among browsers, but not enough to make 15K choices tractable for a text facet (and besides 15K is too many for a human to manipulate effectively). I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I'd suggest stepping back and rethinking how you tackle the problem. e.g. Can you filter by some criteria first to make the number more manageable?

Comment: I'm working on annual membership lists of the same organization over a 60 year period. The cluster function works well for reconciling variants of the same person's name due to strange printing and bad OCR. This procedure has worked great for smaller samples, and this is the first time I've had performance problems. BUT--I tried the file on a computer with a faster processor and performance is acceptable.

Comment: One thing which might not be obvious is that you can use "Cluster & Edit" to get directly to the clustering functionality without first having to go through the text list facet.